# Send cmd to ESP8266 from web server

Tags: esp8266

I have just started studying about IoT a few days ago, and now I'm trying to work with the wifi module ESP8266.
I want to do something like this: I send a cmd from Android device to a server, which have some php code to handle my GET or POST data. Then, it will send some data, like json or something, to the ESP8266, and to a micro controller like AVR via UART to handle the changes. And sometime the MCU can send some data to server, and server will noti the android (a reverse process).
I have understood how to send data from wifi module to an URL with Get and Post method (not fully, but maybe enough). I just dont understand how to send message from server to the module! Does the module need to send request to server and get the respone again and again in a loop?!
I am a newbie so please give me a clear and answer! Thanks and sorry for bad English =)

Comment: The MQTT protocol is much better suited for your use case than HTTP. There are lots of tutorials on the net on how to connect an ESP8266 with a android phone using MQTT.

Comment: First time heard about MQTT! I will try out! Thanks :D

Answer (score 2):

In general servers do not *push* data to devices for several reasons. The most obvious reason is that the devices are behind routers which effectively hide them from the Internet.

> Does the module need to send request to server and get the respone again and again in a loop?

Yes, that is the usual method. The device just needs regular Internet access and routers are usually configured to allow outbound HTTP traffic.

---

As this isn't an electrical design question it will probably be migrated to one of the other SE sites.

Comment: Thanks for your answer :D I will try getting data with a loop. Not sure how much power it will take?

Answer (score 0):

You could set up a MQTT broker (available both to the server and the ESP, so you would have figure out the networking and security).

The ESP would subscribe to a particular topic. On the server side you could use phpMQTT to connect to the broker and publish an event. The broker would then notify the ESP.